# Generate C# class(.cs) model files from .csdl files

Tags: c#, xml, schema, csdl

I have a .csdl file downloaded and am trying to convert them to model class files (.cs). I tried edmgen which did not work because I was using "http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" as the schema.

When i use edmgen with the command mentioned in comments I receive and error saying " the EDM Schema argument is not valid " and the EDM schema is "http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" which I cannot change to other schemas.

What is the best way to do the conversion using the above schema?

Comment: Please include a code sample showing us what you've tried and include as much details as possible.

Comment: **"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:EntityClassGeneration /incsdl:.\<inputFileName>.csdl /outobjectlayer:.\<outputFileName>.cs /language:CSharp**  This is the code I used when I tried with edmgen

Comment: The schema link you provided are only a subset of the entire schema.  You have to create your own top level schema that uses the link shown.